# Problem with 2 command in 1 vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have a little problem with a simple vbScript. The script has to run 2 action one after the other.

```
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell
Dim Yesterday
Dim resultat
Dim commande
Dim Jour

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Yesterday =  DateAdd("d", -2, Date())
resultat = "00001"
resultat = resultat & Right(Year(Yesterday), 2)
Jour = (Datepart("y", Yesterday))

If ((Jour < 100) and (Jour > 9)) Then resultat = resultat & "0" & Jour

If (Jour < 10) Then resultat = resultat & "00" & Jour

If (Jour >= 100) Then resultat = resultat & Jour

resultat = """(&(objectClass=eTGlobalUser)(eTSuspended=0)(eTRoleDN=*)(eTUpdateDate>=" & resultat & "))"""

commande = GetScriptPath() & "PharosGDH.exe /ldapfilter:" & resultat & " /conso"
WshShell.Run commande, 5, true
commande2 = GetScriptPath() & "PharosGDH.exe /all /auditPharos
WshShell.Run commande2, 5, true
WScript.Quit 1

Function GetScriptPath()
    GetScriptPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
End Function
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong please?

Sorry the declaration was missing on the copy/past, And the windows juste shutdown silently, after that i see that result is not has it suposed to be!

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong? Do you get an error? Does it fail silently? Does the first Action run but the second not, does the second action run, but the first not. More information please.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only help you fix it, but you have to tell us what is wrong yourself. In other words, why do you think something is wrong? Does it not do what you hoped it would? Does it crash? Does it produce the wrong results? We need something to go on.

Comment: Isn't jour French for day? Why are you storing the year in it?

Comment: Datepart("y", ...) gets the "day of year". So, that is correct. To get the year, you have to use Datepart("yyyy", ....).

See <http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_vbs_ufbq.mspx?mfr=true>

Comment: Yes i m french, that's why my english smells so bad... and i have to make a timestamp from the date of yesterday but dont worry about that part, i've done a lot of echo and the date query is done right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your actual code? There are at least two syntax errors in it:

First syntax error:

```
commande2 = GetScriptPath() & "PharosGDH.exe /all /auditPharos
```

There are double quotes missing at the end of the line:

```
commande2 = GetScriptPath() & "PharosGDH.exe /all /auditPharos"
```

Second syntax error:

```
Dim resultat
Dim commande
Dim Jour
```

The variable "commande2" is used, but not declared. Use:

```
Dim resultat
Dim commande
Dim commande2
Dim Jour
```

If this does not fix your problem, as the others have said, please tell us, what the problem is: Error message? Wrong behaviour?

## Second attempt

Maybe display the commands used before executing them to be able to check that they contain the right content:

```
commande = GetScriptPath() & "PharosGDH.exe /ldapfilter:" & resultat & " /conso"
WshShell.Popup commande
WshShell.Run commande1, 5, true
commande2 = GetScriptPath() & "PharosGDH.exe /all /auditPharos"
WshShell.Popup commande
WshShell.Run commande2, 5, true
WScript.Quit 1
```